# Problem hosting wcfservice on mydoamin.com

Tags: wcf-hosting

I have an asp.net and a wcf service created. I hosted wcfservice on localhost(IIS) and the as.net web application also on IIS. Both work fine. I want to host both wcf and my asp.net web application on a registered domain. But when I right click on wcf service & click on publish and eneter details of the site I got error

> ""The "IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded" task failed unexpectedly.
>               System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly
>                    'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=7.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>                PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system
>              cannot find the file specified."
>            Affte googleing I installed MSwebdeplot v2 on my machine &
>   tried again. but this             tiel I get error "Web deployment
>   task failed. (Attempt by               method
>   'Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeployDriverInCmd.LogTrace
>   (Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentTraceEventArgs)' to access type
>   'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterEventArgs' failed.)  "

I tried to get solution from internet but no luck. pls help me. I have attached the screen shot also.

Answer (score 0):

You need this: http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

Comment: I have already installed webdeploy on my machine after taht i got thsi error